# How do I update the polyline (removing the previous one from the map) by dragging a marker which changes the path?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm fairly new to Javascript and Google Maps API and I've seen various variations of this question but I'm unable to get any of the solutions to apply to my code, and I'm not sure why.  As the polyline is defined within the function, shouldn't it be redefined every time the function is called, effectively removing the previous one?  Or am I missing something? What can I do to remove the "old" polyline, when the marker is dragged?

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/emvee/qqavw3gh/6/

The relevant lines of code are lines 44-53 (the events for when the marker is dragged and in the process of being dragged) and lines 171-215, which is the function that defines and draws the polyline, based on directions it receives from directionsService.

```
//map details, i.e. creates a map of Lucca
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8430, 10.5050),
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

//create map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

//marker details
var markerOptions1 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8402250, 10.5008083)
};
var markerOptions2 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.83811, 10.50328)
};
var markerOptions3 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8439194, 10.5032083)
};
var markerOptions4 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8405167, 10.5038722)
};

//creates markers
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions1);
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions2);
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions3);
var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions4);

//Draggable marker for the start of pathing
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

var startMarkerOptions = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8376806, 10.5060250),
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  title: "Drag me to your current locaton!",
  icon: image
}

var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker(startMarkerOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'dragend', function(evt) {
  console.log("Marker dropped.");
  console.log(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3));
  console.log(evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3));
  calcRoute();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'dragstart', function(evt) {
  console.log("marker is being dragged");
});

//sets markers
marker1.setMap(map);
marker2.setMap(map);
marker3.setMap(map);
marker4.setMap(map);

//content string for infoWindows
var contentString1 = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Via della Caserma alleyway</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4veClkp.jpg" width="100" height="150" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/cUIGkWD.jpg" alt="alleyway1" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/wYokWoy.jpg" alt="3headstencil" width="100" height="136" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/UKI1Hmf.jpg" alt="resTU2" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/fhN88hs.jpg" alt="alleyway2" width="100" height="150" />' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

var contentString2 = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Various Artists on Legal Walls</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/hWt5kD1.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Syedh0I.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/poNqEaq.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/pOZxM0p.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1kAlmlk.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/eQkWHgl.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TGvXhcV.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/NrJd1Tn.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/hxfBhl7.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4VUjHa1.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CL5EmVj.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/buHkEfj.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/KZIRQJL.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gOm3tNd.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

var contentString3 = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Octopus on Via Buia</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/0tOabHO.jpg" alt="Test Image" width="100" height="150" />'
'</div>' +
'</div>';


//marker info windows
var infoWindowOptions1 = {
  content: contentString1
};

var infoWindowOptions2 = {
  content: contentString2
};

var infoWindowOptions3 = {
  content: contentString3
};

var infoWindowOptions4 = {
  content: 'Resta and Various Artists'
};

//Events for clicking on the markers
var infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions1);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow1.open(map, marker1);
});

var infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions2);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow2.open(map, marker2);
});

var infoWindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions3);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow3.open(map, marker3);
});

var infoWindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions4);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow4.open(map, marker4);
});


var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var waypts = [];

stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8402250, 10.5008083)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.83811, 10.50328)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8439194, 10.5032083)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8405167, 10.5038722)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});

function calcRoute() {

  start = startMarker.getPosition();
  end = startMarker.getPosition();

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: "#58FA58",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    //console.log(response.routes[0].legs);
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
      for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        var steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
          //console.log(steps[j].instructions);
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            poly.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong" + status);
    }
  });

  poly.setMap(map);
  //poly.setPath([]); why does this not work?
}

calcRoute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the polyline global, remove it from the map  (set its `map` property to null) before creating the new one (once you create the new one, you lose access to it, and if it isn't global, it goes out of scope when you exits the `calcRoute` function).

```
if (poly && poly.setMap) poly.setMap(null);
poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: [],
  strokeColor: "#58FA58",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 3
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qqavw3gh/7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
//map details, i.e. creates a map of Lucca
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8430, 10.5050),
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};
var poly;


//create map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

//marker details
var markerOptions1 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8402250, 10.5008083)
};
var markerOptions2 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.83811, 10.50328)
};
var markerOptions3 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8439194, 10.5032083)
};
var markerOptions4 = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8405167, 10.5038722)
};

//creates markers
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions1);
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions2);
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions3);
var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions4);

//Draggable marker for the start of pathing
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

var startMarkerOptions = {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8376806, 10.5060250),
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  title: "Drag me to your current locaton!",
  icon: image
}

var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker(startMarkerOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'dragend', function(evt) {
  console.log("Marker dropped.");
  console.log(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3));
  console.log(evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3));
  calcRoute();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'dragstart', function(evt) {
  console.log("marker is being dragged");
});

//update the marker's coordinates for the pathing
/*
   function markerCoords(startMarker){
google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'dragend', function(evt){

    });

});

google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'drag', function(evt){
    console.log("marker is being dragged");
}); */
//end of marker coordinate update

//sets markers
marker1.setMap(map);
marker2.setMap(map);
marker3.setMap(map);
marker4.setMap(map);

//content string for infoWindows
var contentString1 = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Via della Caserma alleyway</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4veClkp.jpg" width="100" height="150" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/cUIGkWD.jpg" alt="alleyway1" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/wYokWoy.jpg" alt="3headstencil" width="100" height="136" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/UKI1Hmf.jpg" alt="resTU2" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/fhN88hs.jpg" alt="alleyway2" width="100" height="150" />' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

var contentString2 = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Various Artists on Legal Walls</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/hWt5kD1.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Syedh0I.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/poNqEaq.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/pOZxM0p.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1kAlmlk.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/eQkWHgl.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TGvXhcV.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/NrJd1Tn.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/hxfBhl7.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4VUjHa1.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CL5EmVj.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/buHkEfj.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/KZIRQJL.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gOm3tNd.jpg" width="150" height="100" />' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

var contentString3 = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Octopus on Via Buia</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/0tOabHO.jpg" alt="Test Image" width="100" height="150" />'
'</div>' +
'</div>';


//marker info windows
var infoWindowOptions1 = {
  content: contentString1
};

var infoWindowOptions2 = {
  content: contentString2
};

var infoWindowOptions3 = {
  content: contentString3
};

var infoWindowOptions4 = {
  content: 'Resta and Various Artists'
};

//Events for clicking on the markers
var infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions1);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow1.open(map, marker1);
});

var infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions2);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow2.open(map, marker2);
});

var infoWindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions3);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow3.open(map, marker3);
});

var infoWindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions4);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function(e) {
  infoWindow4.open(map, marker4);
});


var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var waypts = [];

stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8402250, 10.5008083)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.83811, 10.50328)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8439194, 10.5032083)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8405167, 10.5038722)
waypts.push({
  location: stop,
  stopover: true
});

function calcRoute() {

  start = startMarker.getPosition();
  end = startMarker.getPosition();

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  if (poly && poly.setMap) poly.setMap(null);
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: "#58FA58",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });



  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    //console.log(response.routes[0].legs);
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
      for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        var steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
          //console.log(steps[j].instructions);
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            poly.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong" + status);
    }
  });

  poly.setMap(map);
  //poly.setPath([]); why does this not work?
}

calcRoute();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<h1>Graffmap</h1>
<hr/>
<p>
  Grab and drag the flag marker to indicate your starting position.</p>
<hr/>
<div id="map"></div>
```